# regex to redirect non www to www and subdomain to file

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, subdomain, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I need to do the following .. have come across various examples but i need to combine three conditions

redirect
1) redirect non www / non subdomain requests. eg :

http://xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com

2) redirect if subdomain is mentioned . eg :

http://user1.xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com/profile?user1

3) redirect to mobile version. eg :

http://m.xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com/m

Tech details : 
I m on IIS ver 6 & using helicontech isapi_rewrite module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

- Match: `^xyzsite.com$`
- Redirect: `www.xyzsite.com`

2.

- Match: `^(?!www.)(.*).xyzsite.com$`
- Redirect: `www.xyzsite.com/profile?$1`

3.

- Match: `^m.(.*)$`
- Redirect: `www.$1/m`

Comment: Can you please explain number 2? I don't understand `(?!=www.)`.

Comment: @SohailAhmed `(?!www)` (there was a typo) is a *negative lookahead*. It asserts the next chars are not "www".

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ISAPI_Rewrite v3 rules (hope this is the version you use):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyzsite\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://www.xyzsite.com [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.xyzsite\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://www.xyzsite.com/m [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.xyzsite\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://www.xyzsite.com/profile?%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

I spent some time on this to hopefuly get you in the right direction. I come up with easiest solution unless you specified a constraint expliciterly. 
This means that I hardcode xyzsite.com in the regex. This actualy higlight the essense more of the solution

1) redirect non www / non subdomain requests. eg : http://xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com

```
pattern:
http://(.*?.com)

replacement:
http://www.$1
```

2) redirect if subdomain is mentioned . eg : http://user1.xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com/profile?user1

```
pattern:
(http://)(.*?)\.(.*)

replacement:
$1www.$3/profile?$2
```

3) redirect to mobile version. eg : http://m.xyzsite.com to http://www.xyzsite.com/m

```
pattern:
http://m\.(.*)

replacement:
http://www.$1/m
```

Hope this helps, Buckley

Comment: your answer to 1) will redirect `http://www.xyzsite.com` to `http://www.www.xyzsite.com`, and then to `http://www.www.www.xyzsite.com` in an infinite redirect loop